# Redirect image request on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inside my application code, for a specific set of APIs, I'm making a NodeJS request like following, which should return a image as the body. This same request works fine on Postman (and I can see the image).

```
module.exports = {
    getThumbnail: function (thumbnailUrn, env, token, onsuccess){
        request({
            url: config.baseURL(env) + config.thumbail(thumbnailUrn),
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            // error check removed for simplicity...
            onsuccess(body);
        });
    }
}
```

The above code run under my own security checks and adds the token header. It works fine (request calls return 200/OK).

Now on my app router I want to respond this as an image, but the output is not being interpreted as an image. Here is what I have:

```
var dm = require(/*the above code*/);

// express router
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/getThumbnail', function (req, res) {
    var urn = req.query.urn;
    dm.getThumbnail(urn, req.session.env, req.session.oauthcode, function (thumb) {
        res.writeHead(200,
            {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png'
            }
        );
        // at this point, the 'thumb' variable is filled
        // but I believe is not properly encoded...
        // or maybe the res.end output is missing something...
        res.end(thumb,  'binary');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT**: as commented by [Nodari Lipartiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2258438/nodari-lipartiya), this is kind of proxy behaviour ( server(responds with image) -> proxy (node.js/resends to client) -> end user)

Comment: Have you tried res.download() helper?

Comment: but I don't want to download the image (i.e. save on the server), just redirect (from original server, through my app, to the user).

Comment: Kind of proxy behaviour ( server(responds with image) -> proxy (node.js/resends to client) -> end user)?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is coming back in `thumb`, but the following snippet seemed to work for me (bypassing Express for simplicity):

```
var http = require("http")
var fs = require("fs")

var server = http.createServer(listener)

server.listen(() => {
    console.log(server.address().port)
})

var binary = fs.readFileSync("path to local image")

function listener(req, resp) {
    resp.writeHead(200,
            {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png'
            }
        );
    resp.end(new Buffer(binary), "binary")
}
```

What happens if you wrap it in a `Buffer`?

Comment: Thanks, that almost did it, just used a 'Buffer(body, 'base64')' on my request and worked fine!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't forget to upvote and accept answers that helped you out!

Comment: already upvoted, but didn't accept answer (not exactly, so don't confuse others)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood everything correctly:
I did this
**server.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/img', function(req, res, next) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream('img.jpeg');
  var filename = "img.jpeg";
  filename = encodeURIComponent(filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="' + filename + '"');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
  stream.pipe(res);
});



app.listen(9999, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 9999!');
});
```

**proxy.js**

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/img', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('proxy/img');
  request({
      url: 'http://localhost:9999/img',
      method: "GET",
  }, function (error, response, body) {
      res.end(body, 'binary');
  });
});



app.listen(9998, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 9998!');
});
```

**req.js**

```
var request = require('request');


request({
      url: 'http://localhost:9998/img',
      method: "GET",
  }, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('body', body);
  });
```

works for me. Please, let me know if you'll need help.

Comment: You can also encode/decode to/from base64 - I think sending images as base64 encoded message is more appropriate